# Touch swipe not working in Windows 8 IE 10 phone

Tags: jquery, windows-phone

we have tried capturing the event using following code in our JQuery.. but swipe is not working.

```
if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) {
  this.element.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", eventHandlerName, false);
  this.element.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", eventHandlerName, false);
  this.element.addEventListener("MSPointerUp", eventHandlerName, false);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use css style for slider element.:

```
-ms-touch-action: none;
```

**[See this](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/15/adapting-your-webkit-optimized-site-for-internet-explorer-10.aspx#step4)**

Comment: yes used in div style.. but still the problem exists

Comment: works for me. Thanks Milind. I also added it in a div style.

Answer (score 0):

Found this question, the answer above did not work for me too, what did work was:

```
html, img {
    -ms-content-zooming: none;
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none; 
}
```